# Query regarding MI and NMI in the context of image fusion

Tags: matlab, information-theory, image-processing, mutual-information

I am exploring Mutual Information (MI) and Normalized Mutual Information (NMI) in the context of image fusion. While reviewing various sources, it's often mentioned that Mutual Information's value signifies the quality of fusion, with higher values indicating better fusion. However, I'm curious about what constitutes a high value.

What is the range of Mutual Information values in the context of image fusion? Most sources suggest that higher values are better, but what range would be considered notably high or indicative of good fusion quality?

Furthermore, regarding Normalized Mutual Information (NMI), I understand that it should ideally fall within the 0-1 range, signifying the quality of the registration. However, in academic papers, the reported values often hover around 0.x or 1.x. What exactly should be anticipated in terms of value range for an effectively registered fusion image?

Like see the values of NMI from one of the papers NMI:

```
0.8316, 0.8352, 1.1684, 0.5978, 0.9891, 1.0071, 1.2135, 1.1879, 
1.1198, 0.9010, 0.9585, 1.1968, 1.1082, 1.0031, 1.2485
```

I'm seeking clarification on the expected range or thresholds for Mutual Information and Normalized Mutual Information values to better interpret the quality of image fusion. Any insights or references to comprehensive explanations would be greatly appreciated.

You can check the "metricMI.m" at metric toolbox - https://github.com/zhengliu6699/imageFusionMetrics

Comment: Could you reference or link some of your sources?

Comment: Yes, as there are many sources, i can post one or two, from which you can get clarity
1. Reference - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1566253516302081?casa_token=QqebcarAusIAAAAA:cLnoo82o8pUdr82-I3JNP7bjFyZl9aIfCWBMvl09pm-qFKlRXpu9IuX2Z6VJQoxvmzkGr8N_e95L
2. https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/ICCV2021/html/Xiao_DTMNet_A_Discrete_Tchebichef_Moments-Based_Deep_Neural_Network_for_Multi-Focus_ICCV_2021_paper.html?ref=https://githubhelp.com

You can check them from google scholar also, if you are not able to open it from here as they are sci papers.

Comment: In these links please check the experimental result section, where they have clearly mentioned that they have used Normalized MI and check the values of MI from table also. Thankyou.